# How to delete rows (NOT columns) in a csv file

Tags: python, csv, rows

I am trying to delete a particular row (NOT a column) in a `csv` file for a 
class project.  When I deleted columns I put:

```
r=row 
r[22], r[21]
# and so on
```

So how do I specify that I want to delete rows?  I am working with census data and want to get rid of that extra row of headers that are always in census tables.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Do you to want to physically delete the first line of the file, or do you just want the csv reader to ignore it?

Answer (score 0):

Convert your csv reader to a list and slice the appropriate indexes off:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    rows = list(reader)[1:]  # no more header row
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas, it's so easy to handle data and files with it. Use it to edit your data easily.

You can open your csv file and convert it to a pandas dataframe through.

```
df = pandas.read_csv('file.csv')
```

After that you can use this function.

```
df.drop(df.columns[[0]], axis=1)
```

In this example I'm deleting the row with index 0.

[Pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/)